# Header position CSS

Tags: html, css

```
#Header
    {               
    font: normal 14px/100% Playfair Display, serif;;
    color: #2c3e50;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    }
```

And it looks like this

It has an empty space around it [Example 1](http://pokit.org/get/img/94809bffca2490fb293d2fb75d314e93.jpg)

If i set the position to  `position:fixed;`

Then my text was under that header

HTML Code:

```
<div id='Header'>
    <table bgcolor="#f5deb3" width="100%">
        <tr  height="50px">
        <td>    
             Sometext
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/u3ZuL/1/)) to your CSS file:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

It looks like the spacing is coming from the body's padding.

Comment: Wow i spend hour on google by searching for that solution :( .. It wasn't so hard. Thanks for your help